# My application encrypts pdf files OK with itext on local server but fails on QA server

Tags: java, pdf, encryption, itext

I 'm using the library itext version 5.5.4 and bounce castle 1.49. My application works fine on my local server and server development . The following statement is used to encrypt :

```
String userPassord = "4888";
String OwnerPassword = "4850";

writer.setEncryption ( getBytes ( userPassword ) , getBytes ( OwnerPassword ) ,   PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128) ;

private byte[] getBytes(String str){
    return str.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
}
```

The weblogic server (QA environment) returns a 500 error but in the log files no trace that an exception has occurred.

I think the error may be occurring when the instruction " writer.setEncryption " runs because when the application generates PDF files without encryption keys , this works correctly in all environments.

We are using WebLogic 12.1.3 servers in all environments and Java version 1.7

Any idea what may be breaking my application in other environments ? java configuration ? configuration in weblogic servers?

Comment: Having two different versions of BouncyCastle in the CLASSPATH could cause this problem. I assume you are shipping BC 1.49 with your jar, but maybe WebLogic has an older BC version living at the level of the application server.

Comment: *a 500 error but in the log files no trace that an exception has occurred.* - that's something you should concentrate on. If there is a 500, there should be some log for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Bruno and Mkl, the error was:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: class org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive overrides final method equals.(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:412)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:366)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:318)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:80)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:186)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:50)
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfEncryption.<init>(PdfEncryption.java:149)
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.setEncryption(PdfWriter.java:2131)
```

Solution in weblogic.xml:

```
<wls:container-descriptor>
    <wls:prefer-application-packages>
        <wls:package-name>org.bouncycastle</wls:package-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>      
</wls:container-descriptor>
```

Based in:
Configuring a Filtering ClassLoader
To configure the FilteringClassLoader to specify that a certain package is loaded from an application, add a prefer-application-packages descriptor element to weblogic-application.xml which details the list of packages to be loaded from the application. The following example specifies that org.apache.log4j.* and antlr.* packages are loaded from the application, not the system classloader:

```
<prefer-application-packages>
  <package-name>org.apache.log4j.*</package-name>
  <package-name>antlr.*</package-name>
</prefer-application-packages>
```

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLPRG/classloading.htm#WLPRG315